# Faded Questions?

Tags: support

I am seeing some questions faded out. They don't appear to be closed, deleted, or anything of the sort.  They are just at 50% opacity.

Does anyone know ***why***?

Answer (score 6):

Ah, figured it out.

You can choose to "ignore" certain topics, which cause those questions with that tag to be faded out slightly.